# Dúvida sobre o NgFor

Tags: angular, typescript

Boa noite pessoal,

Gostaria de fazer com que um select interagisse com o outro e ambos possuem um NgFor que faz a listagem dentro das tags option.
O problema é que para que a listagem do segundo select carregue eu preciso da index do primeiro select.

Código:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div>
  < p > Selecionar um select, para depois o outro.</p>
  < div >
  <select name="">
  <option value="" *ngFor="let lista of lista; let i=index" id= "{{i}}" >
  {{ lista.cliente }}
  </option>
  < /select>
  < p > Outro Select, deve conter os produtos do cliente selecionado no select anterior < /p>
    < select >
    <option value="let produto of lista" >
      {{ produto.produtos }}
</option>
  < /select>
  < /div>
  < /div>`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public lista: any = [{
      cliente: 'Rodolpho',
      produtos: [{
        nome: 'Sony PS4'
      }, {
        nome: 'Nintendo Switch'
      }]
    },
    {
      cliente: 'Gabriela',
      produtos: [{
        nome: 'Xbox One'
      }]
    }

  ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Não sei se ficou clara minha dúvida, mas basicamente eu preciso selecionar um item do array e o index eu uso pra colocar no segundo ngFor pra carregar aos produtos correspondentes do cliente selecionado.

Comment: Fácil de fazer, chato de explicar.  O seu primeiro select vai ser alimentado por essa sua lista inicial e o segundo select vai ser alimentado por outro array (ainda vazio).  Quando o usuário selecionar o item nesse primeiro select, vc chama uma função q vai atribuir lista[indice].produto ao array q alimenta o segundo select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu primeiro select vai ser alimentado por essa sua lista inicial e o segundo select vai ser alimentado por outro array (ainda vazio). Quando o usuário selecionar o item nesse primeiro select, vc chama uma função q vai atribuir lista[indice].produto ao array q alimenta o segundo select.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
 `
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of lista; let i = index" [value]="i">
  {{item.cliente}}
  </option>
  </select>
  <select>
  <option *ngFor="let prod of produto">
  {{prod.nome}}
  </option>
  </select>
`

})

class MyApp {
  produto: Array<any>;
  lista: any = [{
      cliente: 'Rodolpho',
      produtos: [{
        nome: 'Sony PS4'
      }, {
        nome: 'Nintendo Switch'
      }]
    },
    {
      cliente: 'Gabriela',
      produtos: [{
        nome: 'Xbox One'
      }]
    }
  ];

onChange(valor) {
     this.produto = this.lista[valor].produtos;
  }
```

Segue sniped.

https://codepen.io/ccastroelo/pen/JyJBMr