# Como usar uma tag Html direto no meu objeto?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

Exemplo, quero fazer uma lista com a tag HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>primeiro item</li>
  <li>segundo item</li>
  <li>terceiro item</li>
</ul>
```

E o meu objeto está assim

```
teste = {nome: "primeiro item segundo item terceiro item"}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: e o que já tentou fazer? já viu as perguntas aqui no site com ideias similares, como essa:[ngFor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228259/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-o-ngfor) ?

Comment: Eduardo Vargas, no meu objeto está assim certo? teste = {nome: "primeiro item segundo item terceiro item"} eu quero fazer isso dentro do objeto teste = {nome: "<ul><li>primeiro </li> <li>item segundo</li><li> item terceiro item</li>"} e esse objeto automaticamente já formata e fica uma lista. Deu pra entender irmão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro vc tem que separar sua string em um array de substrings baseado em alguma coisa.
 Por exemplo por espaços:

```
meuArray:string[]

ngOnInit(){
teste = {nome: "primeiro item segundo item terceiro item"}
this.meuArray= teste.nome.split(' ');
}
```

E depois só usar o ngFor no seu array

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor"let item of meuArray">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, vou tentar aqui. Abraços e muito obrigado.